# What offspring would result from a high elf mother and a shadar-kai elf father?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, lore, elf, shadar-kai

I got into a debate with one of my players. They claimed that their character having a (full) high elf mother and a (full) shadar-kai elf father would be considered a high half-elf, and should use the *Player's Handbook* half-elf features and traits. But I disagree and think that it would make them a full elf - either a high elf like the mother, or a shadar-kai like the father.

I want the player to stick to only official races for character creation. I just feel that 2 elf sub-races are different enough to make only a half race.

**What offspring would a high elf mother and a shadar-kai elf father make?**

1. Full high elf
2. Full shadar-kai elf
3. High half-elf
4. Half-shadar-kai
5. Human

I'm trying to stick with the official D&D 5E lore.

Comment: Is this purely from a lore perspective or mechanics? There are no rules for "Half X Elf", and definitely not for being half of one thing half of another.

Answer (score 8):

### Rules-as-written, they must pick one subrace of elf.

#### Rules-based answer: Pick one or the other.

According to *Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes*, the shadar-kai are a subrace of elf. This excludes half-elf and human as possible offspring. A half-elf is defined as the offspring of an elf and a human, while a human is a different race from elf entirely.

There are no specific rules for the offspring of two different subraces of elves. However, *Player's Handbook*, p.23, defines the following rule for playing an elf:

> Ancient divides among the elven people resulted in three main subraces: high elves, wood elves, and dark elves, who are commonly called drow. **Choose one of these subraces.**

*Mordenainen's Tome of Foes* additionally adds three subraces:

> At the DM's discretion, you have access to more sub-races for elf characters, in addition to the subraces in the *Player's Handbook*. When you choose the subrace of your elf, **you can choose one of the following options**: eladrin, sea elf, or shadar-kai.

Rules-as-written, then, the player must pick either the statistics of a high elf or a shadar-kai elf. Anything else, such as some homebrew mix of the two, must be ruled upon by the DM.

#### Lore answer: Canonically undefined

The lore of the shadar-kai as elves is thus far restricted to *Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes*. This is because shadar-kai were not canonically elves prior to 5th edition. They were described in 4th edition as humanlike, rather than elves.

In other words, the description of the shadar-kai in *Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes* is the sole source of lore on that race as regards their offspring with a high elf. That work does not define any such offspring, meaning that it is undefined.

Comment: Note that in Fiend Folio (3.0) they were fey speaking elven.

Comment: Sidenote: SCAG also lists some [half-elf variants](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/scag/races-of-the-realms#MixedHeritage) (p. 116), one of which is "high half-elf" (along with drow half-elf, wood half-elf, and aquatic half-elf). Also, XGtE's "This Is Your Life" section has a ["Half-Elf Parents"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/xgte/character-options-this-is-your-life#HalfElfParents) table (p. 62), where the 4 listed parent combinations are elf & human, elf & half-elf, human & half-elf, or 2 half-elves. (There's no such parents table for elf characters.)

Comment: "A half-elf is defined as the offspring of an elf and a human" Or a half-elf and an elf or human.